# Not work clock! with animate with XeLaTeX

Tags: beamer, animate, tdclock

Not work clock! with animate with XeLaTeX

Edit Code:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{animate,color}
    \usepackage[timeinterval=1,font=Helv]{tdclock}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \initclock
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{1}
    \strut\emph{\textcolor{red}{Remark:}}\newframe[3]
    \end{animateinline}
    This is test of animate And tdclock packages.
    \begin{center}
    \alert{Not work clock!}
    \\
    \tdtime 
    \\
    %\crono
\cronohours\pdfcolon\cronominutes\pdfcolon\cronoseconds
    \end{center}

    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

a) Windows 7 operating system
b) pdfviewer: Adobe Reader XI versian 11.0.09
c) TexLive 2018

upload [Output](http://s9.picofile.com/d/8341167684/da38d876-8570-45d4-975f-55814ff85557/test_clock.pdf)

Comment: Which pdfviewer do you use? Which operating system do you have? `tdclock` works only in some viewers.

Comment: Off-topic: the syntax `\color{red}{Remark:}` is wrong. Use either `\color{red}Remark:` or `\textcolor{red}{Remark:}`

Comment: Thanks for help.a) Windows 7 operating system b) pdfviewer: Adobe Reader XI versian 11.0.09 c) TexLive 2018

Comment: adobe reader looks good. I just tested your code and it works fine with adobe reader XI. Which engine do you use for compiling? `tdclock` can be used for example with pdflatex, but won't work with xelatex.

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice, I've run with XeLaTeX engine. When using the animated package with tdclock, this problem occurs. Only one of them works correctly with XeLaTeX.